# How to secure/locked mdf file on Client Machine

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I have developed Windows Application using Visual Studio 2012 and needs to deploy it on client Machine along with database .mdf file.

I have gone through many technical forums in order to obtain solution for security issue related to mdf file but most of them suggesting use of SQL Server Enterprise Edition with Transparent Data Encryption feature.

But I just wanted to keep database locked/hidden from client machine and don't want to encrypt the database. Is there any feature/solution available with SQL Server Express Edition where we can hide/lock the mdf file from client.

Comment: If the `.mdf` file is *on the client computer* - you're lost, there's no way you can *lock* or *hide* it - period. The malicious user could copy it to another machine and attach it to a SQL Server instance and have full control over the structure and contents of the file. The only reliable way to secure this is by keeping the file on a server under your control, managing physical as well as electronic access to it, and make sure no one can grab your `.mdf` file ....

Comment: Can you explain the goals you are trying to achieve? No, locking / hiding is impossible, forget about that. But what you want is most probably achievable by other means.

Comment: @RogerWolf I just want to keep mdf file secure from client. My requirement is client should not be able to open the database file and to obtain logical structure of database.

Comment: @rahul16590, no way. You have to store your data someplace else, definitely not on the client computer.